# Ssecond and third level excitations of open string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory

Following David Tong's lectures on string theory, I considered the second and third level excitations of open string. For simplicity, let's set the spacetime dimension = 4, so the transverse dimension is just 2.

The first excited states are $a_{-1}^1\left|{0}\right>$ and $a_{-1}^2\left|{0}\right>$ (superscripts label dimension). They are the two polarizations of the photon, or, the vector rep of SO(2).

The second excited states are $a_{-1}^1 a_{-1}^1 \left|{0}\right>$, $a_{-1}^1 a_{-1}^2 \left|{0}\right>$, $a_{-1}^2 a_{-1}^2 \left|{0}\right>$, $a_{-2}^1 \left|{0}\right>$, $a_{-2}^2 \left|{0}\right>$. These five states are recognized as the symmetric traceless rank-2 rep of SO(3). Hence, they are massive spin-2.

For the third level, I reckon there are 10 states. However, the symmetric traceless rank-3 tensors have dimension 7 not 10 (though symmetric rank-3 tensors have dimension 10). So, how to interpret these 10 states as spin-3?

Or it is a problem that it is not legit to simply work in D=4? (This also raises another general question, in D=26, what is the general formula for number of states at level n? And how to interpret level n as spin n?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you don't require Lorentz invariance, it is perfectly OK to work in four dimensions.

How many states do you have at each level ? You can convince yourself, as an exercise, that at level $k$, the number of states is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the function $$\prod\limits_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{(1-x^m)^2} = 1 + 2x + 5x^2 + 10x^3 + 20 x^4 + \dots $$

Now clearly those numbers do not coincide with the dimensions of the irreducible representations of $SO(3)$, which are the odd integers. The reason is simply that the representations to which the string states belong are not irreducible. The 10-dimensional representation is the sum of a spin 3 and a spin 1.

One way to see that is to refine the generating function given above. For that, include an additional variable $s$ that will "count the spin": $$\prod\limits_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{(1-s^2x^m)(1-s^{-2}x^m)} = 1+\left(s^2+\frac{1}{s^2}\right)
   x+\left(s^4+\frac{1}{s^4}+s^2+\frac{1}{s^2}+1\right)
   x^2+\left(s^6+\frac{1}{s^6}+s^4+\frac{1}{s^4}+2
   s^2+\frac{2}{s^2}+2\right)
   x^3+\left(s^8+\frac{1}{s^8}+s^6+\frac{1}{s^6}+3
   s^4+\frac{3}{s^4}+3 s^2+\frac{3}{s^2}+4\right)
   x^4 \dots $$
The coefficient of $x^3$ is the sum of the character of a spin 3, $s^6+\frac{1}{s^6}+s^4+\frac{1}{s^4}+2
   s^2+\frac{1}{s^2}+1$, and a spin 1, $s^2+\frac{1}{s^2}+1$.

For another example, let us consider level 4. Here the character is $$s^8+\frac{1}{s^8}+s^6+\frac{1}{s^6}+3
   s^4+\frac{3}{s^4}+3 s^2+\frac{3}{s^2}+4$$. To decompose it, we can start with the highest weight, $s^8$. This is spin 4. We remove the spin 4 character, $s^8+\frac{1}{s^8}+s^6+\frac{1}{s^6}+
   s^4+\frac{1}{s^4}+1 s^2+\frac{1}{s^2}+1$ and we are left with $2
   s^4+\frac{2}{s^4}+2 s^2+\frac{2}{s^2}+3$. We see that the highest weight is $2s^4$, so we have two spin 2. Removing $2 \left(
   s^4+\frac{1}{s^4}+ s^2+\frac{1}{s^2}+1 \right)$, we are left with $1$, which is a spin 0. Conclusion: the level 4 is one spin 4, two spin 2 and one spin 0. The dimensions add up to $9 + 2 \cdot 5 + 1 = 20$.

You can play the same game at any level, and observe that except at level 1, you can always cast the spectrum into (in general reducible) representations of $SO(3)$.

**Edit : how to tell which states give which spins**

For that, you can refine even more the generating function. Let us take a different fugacity for each oscillator level, 
$$\prod\limits_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{(1-s^2x^m \alpha_{-m})(1-s^{-2}x^m \alpha_{-m})} =1+x \left(\alpha _{-1} s^2+\frac{\alpha _{-1}}{s^2}\right)+x^2
   \left(\alpha _{-1}^2+\alpha _{-1}^2 s^4+\frac{\alpha
   _{-1}^2}{s^4}+\alpha _{-2} s^2+\frac{\alpha
   _{-2}}{s^2}\right)+x^3 \left(2 \alpha _{-2} \alpha _{-1}+\alpha
   _{-1}^3 s^6+\frac{\alpha _{-1}^3}{s^6}+\alpha _{-2} \alpha _{-1}
   s^4+\frac{\alpha _{-2} \alpha _{-1}}{s^4}+\alpha _{-1}^3
   s^2+\alpha _{-3} s^2+\frac{\alpha _{-1}^3}{s^2}+\frac{\alpha
   _{-3}}{s^2}\right)+ \dots$$
Let us look for instance at level 3. You see that the spin 3 is made by states of the form $\alpha_{-1}^3$ and $\alpha _{-2} \alpha _{-1}$, while the spin 1 is made of states of the form $\alpha_{-3}$ and $\alpha _{-2} \alpha _{-1}$.

Comment: Am I right to say that the level 4 is the sum of spin 0 + spin 1 + spin 3 + spin 4? This is only way to sum up to 20...

Comment: Also, does the first formula generalize to D dimensions? And is there a way to tell which of the 10 states at level 3 are spin 1 and spin 3?

Comment: No, level 4 is spin 4, two spin 2 and spin 0. I have edited my answer to provide details.

Comment: Yes, the formula generalizes to arbitrary dimension. And yes, you can tell which states give which spins. using these generating functions, you can for instance take different fugacities $x_m$ for $m \geq 1$ that represent the operators $\alpha_{-m}^i$.

Comment: I guess for D transverse dimensions, the number of states at level n is given by $\prod 1/(1-x^m)^D$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I added in the answer an explanation for how to identify which states give which spins.