# Spin of higher string excitations

Tags: hilbert-space, angular-momentum, string-theory

I am trying to better understand spin in string theory.
There is already a good post here:

[Ssecond and third level excitations of open string](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327522/)

But I have these questions:

1) Why would the second excited stated be spin-2?
If I use the spin operator then I find states which have
spin eigenvalues of +/-2, of +/-1 and of 0.
Take the spin operator $E^{\mu\nu}= -i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}(\alpha^{\mu}_{-n}\alpha^{\nu}_n-\alpha^{\nu}_{-n}\alpha^{\mu}_n)$ in some specific direction.

Spin 1: $[E^{ij},\alpha_{-2}^i+i\alpha_{-2}^j]=\alpha^{i}_{-2}+i\alpha^{j}_{-2}$
so that $E^{ij}(\alpha_{-2}^i+i\alpha_{-2}^j)|0>=(\alpha_{-2}^i+i\alpha_{-2}^j)|0>$

Spin 0: $[E^{ij},(\alpha_{-1}^i)^2+(\alpha_{-1}^j)^2]=0$ so that $E^{ij}((\alpha_{-1}^i)^2+(\alpha_{-1}^j)^2)|0>=0$

2) When you compactify from $D=10$ to $D=4$, how does that affect spin?

3) What are explicitly the few first levels of the massive spin states for the superstring?

Answer (score 0):

You need more careful extract irreducible representation of little group.

See for example 4.2.2. in Gleb Arutunov notes [Lectures on String Theory](https://www.physik.uni-muenchen.de/lehre/vorlesungen/wise_19_20/TD1_-String-Theory-I/arutyunov_notes.pdf)